# NSXMLElement, without an NSXMLDocument

Tags: objective-c, desktop-application, nsxml

I have an NSXMLElement that is a copy from somewhere else in my code.  After it's been used, it no longer is connected to an NSXMLDocument.  It's (what I believe to be) not linked to anything.

If I NSLog the NSXMLElement, I am given the contents.  I can see it.

But, if I try to use nodesForXPath, it returns nothing.  It's blank.  It cannot find anything (unless I just search for *, in which case it returns everything with /t/t/n/t/t).

Now, if I make that NSXMLElement the root of a NEW NSXMLDocument, and then search the new document, I can search the XPath perfectly!

I am trying to understand the logic there.  I have been reading the documentation, but I haven't found anything that explains what is happening here (or at least, I have no understood it if I did find it in the documentation).

I would really appreciate someone helping me understand exactly why this is happening, and whether or not I need to use this NSXMLDocument.

Here is my code:

**(*element* is an NSXMLElement coming from an NSArray of stored NSXMLElements.  They are copies from a document used in another method)**

```
NSArray* scene = [element nodesForXPath:@"scene[1]" error:nil];
NSLog(@"scene: %@", [[scene objectAtIndex:0] stringValue]);
```

But if I do this, I get a result:

```
NSXMLDocument* docElement = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithRootElement:element];
NSArray* scene = [docElement nodesForXPath:@"scene[1]" error:nil];
NSLog(@"scene: %@", [[scene objectAtIndex:0] stringValue]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because the xpath context used by libxml2 holds a reference to the document. If there is no document, it probably doesn't know how to operate. The behavior if you search for * may just be a special-case because it knows it has to return everything so it doesn't even try to search.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  After doing some messing around and trying it in different scenarios, it looks like you're correct.